# How to insert a list of variable length into wx.ListCtrl or wx.ComboBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a data that I pulled from a SQL database, then put into a dataframe, then converted to a list. I'm creating a GUI that will let you select a part number, then update parts of the database based on what part number is selected. However, I get a single selection in the box that's the ENTIRE list. How can I break up the list into a single selection for each number? I've included the entire GUI and changed a few things so it should work standalone. The length of the list will change dramatically so I can't just individually append each selection.

The GUI is very obviously not finished or formatted correctly so please bear with me in that regard.

```
import wx
import wx.adv
import sqlalchemy
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd

#Reads the SQL Column to use for the dropdown menu
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"
                              "Server=SERVER;"
                              "Database=DB;"
                              "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                              "TrustServerCertificate=yes"
                                                )
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params) 
engine.connect()
#Gets list of Part Numbers for the menubox as well as matching to SQL DF
sqlread = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM Shortage''',engine)
pndf = pd.DataFrame(sqlread, columns = ['PN'])
pndf = pndf[pndf.PN != None]
dflist = pndf.to_string(index=False,header=0)

#I'd just make your own list here to get similar results, but I want to demonstrate that I'm pulling the list from a SQL server
print(dflist)



class compwin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'Shortage Sheet Compiler v0.1',
                          size=(400,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        #textbox printout

        #Prompts for Update Field
        wx.TextCtrl(panel,value = "Update What Part?",size=(100,20),pos=(25,20),style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_NONE)

        #Text Boxes for Update Field
        Combobox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(125,125),pos=(20,40))
        Combobox.EnableCheckBoxes()
        Combobox.Append([dflist])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = compwin()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want every selection in the list "dflist" to be individually selectable. How can I break the list into individual entries, or get the ListCtrl to recognize them as individual entries?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that replicates your problem - too much flab here to wade through

Comment: I'll edit. Sorry, I've been downvoted for providing minimal examples before and was trying to play it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't completely clear why you are having a problem, other than you have not declared the control with a `style=wx.LC_REPORT`, it may be that simple.

```
import wx

dflist = [["123","abc"],["456","def"],["789","ghi"],["132","jkl"],["465","mno"]]

class compwin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'Shortage Sheet Compiler v0.1',
                          size=(400,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        #textbox printout

        #Prompts for Update Field
        wx.TextCtrl(panel,value = "Update What Part?",size=(150,20),pos=(25,20),style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_NONE)

        #Text Boxes for Update Field
        Combobox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300, -1),pos=(25, 50), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        Combobox.InsertColumn(0, "Item", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        Combobox.InsertColumn(1, "Name", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        for item in dflist:
            Combobox.Append((item[0],item[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = compwin()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found that my issue was that I was missing the 

```
for item in dflist:
```
clause. Thanks or your help. Closing.